# Loading int16 data with NULLs from snowflake into a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pyarrow

I am looking for an automated way to fetch data that doesn't fit into numpy datatypes (e.g. nullable ints) from a snowflake db (using the snowflake connector).

E.g. I have a query that loads a column of nullable ints:

```
query = "SELECT MyIntColumn FROM MyTable"
```

where `MyIntColumn` is of type int16 with NULLs.

If I run

```
con = snowflake.connector.connect()
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
```

I have the option of fetching the data via

```
df = cursor.fetch_pandas_all()
```

which returns a `pd.DataFrame` with `MyIntColumn` as `dtype=float`, which is not ideal.

I can instead get it via

```
arrow_data = cursor.fetch_arrow_all()
```

But now I get an arrow table. If I run

```
df = arrow_data.to_pandas()
```

even though I am and pandas 2.0.2, I still get a `float` column.

Is there an automated way that will allow me to preserve the arrow backend types when fetching this data?

Comment: Will ```df["MyIntColumn"].astype("int32")``` work for you? see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html)

Comment: That would work in this specific instance, but I am looking for a solution where a) I don't convert back and forth, and b) this is all done automatically - using `fetch_arrow_all` the types are all correct it's the pandas conversion that looses the correct types that's bothering me. I'm basically looking for something equivalent to the `pd.read_csv` `engine` parameter, like `arrow_data.to_pandas(engine='arrow')` so that pandas uses the pyarrow backend and there is no copying / the types are preserved..